# How to sort a data based on the initial letter

Tags: php, laravel

```php
public function index()
{
    $genres = Genres::all();
    return view('/admin/genres/index')->with('genres', Genres::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get());    
}
```

I want to bring up data in index.blade whose data is retrieved from the database. but when they appear based on the initial letters / sequences of huru 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can order by name

```
$geners = Genres::orderBy('name')->get(); 

return view('admin/genres/index', compact('geners'));
```